# Display Prisma model using model name

Tags: typescript, prisma

I need to create a function that shows a Prisma model using the name of the model as a parameter. Every time the model name can change and TypeScript should automatically check if that Prisma model exists.

```js
/* 
file schema.prisma models:

model User {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  password    String
  job         String   @default("")
  location    String   @default("")
  phone       String   @default("")
  email       String
}

model Participant {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  userID     Int
  groupID    Int
}

*/

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

function loadModel(modelName: /* string */) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const Model = prisma[modelName]
}

loadModel("user")
```

Following code will return a error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.

After that error I tried to add to modelName parameter `: keyof PrismaClient` it worked, but when I tried adding something like Model.create({...}) - it returned following error:

> Property 'create' does not exist on type '(<V extends "beforeExit">(eventType: V, callback: (event: V extends "query" ? QueryEvent : V extends "beforeExit" ? () => Promise : LogEvent) => void) => void) | ... 11 more ... | MessageDelegate<...>'.
> Property 'create' does not exist on type '<V extends "beforeExit">(eventType: V, callback: (event: V extends "query" ? QueryEvent : V extends "beforeExit" ? () => Promise : LogEvent) => void) => void'.

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get error because modelName could be any string, while it can only receive "user" or "participant" (according to schema.prisma model).

So to get list of your model you can get it with **Prisma** type

```js
/* 
file schema.prisma models:

model User {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  password    String
  job         String   @default("")
  location    String   @default("")
  phone       String   @default("")
  email       String
}

model Participant {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  userID     Int
  groupID    Int
}

*/

import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

type PrismaOption = PrismaClient<
  Prisma.PrismaClientOptions,
  never,
  Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined
>

// this will return "user" | "participant"
export type PrismaModel = keyof Omit<
  PrismaOption,
  | "$connect"
  | "$disconnect"
  | "$executeRaw"
  | "$executeRawUnsafe"
  | "$on"
  | "$queryRaw"
  | "$queryRawUnsafe"
  | "$transaction"
  | "$use"
>

function loadModel(modelName: PrismaModel) { // modelName type will be "user" | "participant"
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  return prisma[modelName]
}

loadModel("user")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an open feature request for this to be natively supported in Prisma, if you want to add to it:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5273

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the type imported from the @prisma/client and the [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) lib.

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';
import { User } from '@prisma/client'

const keysOfUser = keys<User>();

console.log(keysOfProps); // ['id', 'name', 'password', ...]
```

Comment: But how will it help me solve my problem?